# Opencv-3.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, scripts, cmake, opencv

I am trying to install opencv-3.1.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. However I face errors when trying to install from `opencv.sh` and `cmake`.

[image: <code>./opencv.sh</code> error]

[image: <code>cmake ..</code> output]

Please advise.

Comment: How did you obtain the `opencv.sh` file? it looks like maybe you copied and pasted it from a website - including line numbering

Comment: I got the opencv.sh file from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV and followed the steps.

Comment: That page may be out of date (notice that it refers to Ubuntu 13.10) - in any case, you need to press the `Toggle line numbers` bar at the top of the script before copying - or download the script from the link provided.

Comment: CMake cannot install the opencv packages. Please see the errors https://docs.google.com/document/d/1d-Y10rP2V5zOmF_m1dakuv4PohvbzsqVOoGtUjk-iwc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can install opencv-3.1.0 from sources using CMake:

> `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
>   /path_to_opencv_directory`
>
> `make -j 8  #"-j 8" means you build opencv in parallel in 8 thread`
>
> `sudo make install  #install opencv to standard directory (/usr/local/)`

For full opencv installation description you can go there: [opencv installation guide](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html)

> P.S.: there is really no need to use any opencv.sh scripts. Everything should be installed intuitively and based on documentation.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), you can now install python on Ubuntu 16.04 as follows:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

for Python3. And

```
pip install opencv-python
```

for Python2.

I hope that helps someone, cheers.